# Agar.io clone using P5JS not ejecting (W) the right direction

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have *attempted* to make an **[agar.io](http://agar.io)** clone using *javaScript* along with *p5js.* Here's the [link](https://github.com/Dev24090/agar.io-clone/) on github for the full source of this project. Now, I've got the basic gist of the game, but now I'm trying to add an eject/split (In the game, by pressing W an ejection happens). But the ejection/w, is not working correctly— Basically, it's firing the w in the wrong direction, usually close to the blob. Here's the part for the ejection(W)'s position relative to the blob's position (the position where the W is fired, [should fire towards the direction of the mouse]):

```
this.update = function() {
        let newvel = createVector(mouseX-width/2, mouseY-height/2);
        newvel.setMag(speed);
        this.vel.lerp(newvel, 0.2);
        this.pos.add(this.vel);
    }
    let pos = createVector(mouseX - (this.pos.x + this.vel.x), mouseY - (this.pos.y + this.vel.y));
```

Don't worry about *the few extra variables/uncalled function*s (lerp, createVector, setMag, & add are all p5JS functions), the code is too long so I only put the part with the update function and the "setting the W's position" part of the code. "this.vel" is basically the *velocity*, so I included it in the W's new position, because as the blob is moving, the W might be eaten instantly.
But it still fires W the wrong direction.... Really need to fix this ...
I tried everything like

`pos = createVector(mouseX - width/2, mouseY - height/2);`

But nevertheless, it still fires the W the wrong direction. *Unfortunately,* I'm not really sure how to approach this the *logical* way :( 
**NOTE:**
I have also used the *translate* function to centre the blobs from *initial position* `(0, 0)`to `translate(width / 2, height / 2)`

Comment: I think your vector may be wrong. I guess its origin is `(0, 0)` (top-left corner?). But it should be the blob right?

Comment: @Pierre C. Yes the origin is `(0,0)` but I used the translate function like this: `translate(width/2, height/2)` to center the blob from `(0,0)`.

Comment: Oh ok so this should be working. Is that normal that you use `this.pos.x` twice in the last line? Shouldn't it be `this.pos.y`?

Comment: @Pierre. Thanks for mentioning it. The *second* `this.pos.x` was a typo I fixed just now; but nevertheless it still fires the exact opposite direction.

Comment: If it's the exact opposite, should the vector be reversed/negated?

Comment: I tried that too. It still doesn't work because it's on the *exact opposite side* __relative__ to the blob

Comment: Here's the [link](https://github.com/Dev24090/agar.io-clone/) on github for the full source of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it, it won't hurt to initialize the ejected blob at `mouseX` and `mouseY` with a translation of *n-displacement*, along with the **constrain** function limiting the blob's position on the current viewport of the map, subtracted by the distance between the blob and the cursor (by using the ***dist*** function). If you would like the animation process to be smoother, and slightly more accurate *curvature-wise* you can use the [lerp](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerp) function on top of it. Figuring out how to order these steps is simple. First get the regular plane coordinate working by translating **before** rendering, then integrating the curves using ***lerp*** to avoid omitting *accuracy* (after the calculations and constrains have been made).

Comment: Wow. I've never considered the velocity that the blob omits when it's moving after it has ejected, and as for the constrain, I guess I'll just have to *lerp* the coordinate, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Not to forget, test it out to see if the base plane coordinate works **before** you fully integrate the *lerp.*